# wp_remote_post not working and server returning 500

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I'm trying to use `wp_remote_post` to register an user in an extern backend.

I have in my wordpress code:

```
$url = 'https://example.com/users/register/';
$response = wp_remote_post( $url, array(
                        'method' => 'POST',
                        'timeout' => 60,
                        'redirection' => 5,
                        'httpversion' => '1.0',
                        'blocking' => true,
                        'headers' => array(),
                        'body' => array( 'email'     => $email,
                                         'name'      => $name,
                                         'last_name' => $last_name,
                                         'password'  => $password),
                        'cookies' => array()                            
                        )
                    );
```

But I'm getting a 500 error:

> [raw] => HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
>       Server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
>       Date: Fri, 29 Sep 2017 17:31:14 GMT
>       Content-Type: text/html
>       Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>       Connection: close
>       X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

I don't know why. I tried the endpoint with postman, curl and an iOS App and it's working. So, I think the problem is somehow with Wordpress. Could it be that I'm making the request from a `http` and not `https`?

This is the nginx log:

```
46.101.102.90 - - [29/Sep/2017:17:31:14 +0000] "POST /users/register/ HTTP/1.1" 500 38 "https://example.com/users/register/" "WordPress/4.8.2; http://www.lifecompanion.eu"
```

so, the request is coming, but somehow it's not working (I already tried `'httpversion' => '1.1'` just in case, and got the same error though.

Maybe someone tried the same, or can tell me a best way to do it.

Comment: Wouldn't this need some kind of authentication? Else anyone can just abuse and create users just like that

Comment: Yep, you're right. But someone didn't want to have it.

Comment: If that was the case you shouldn't have posted the exact URL on this forum. It is as good as exposing someone's website for abuse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the problem is on the server side. If you try to send the data using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, it doesn't like it and returns the 500 status code. However, if it's `multipart/form-data` or `application/json` it works. You also don't need to specify the POST method when you're using `wp_remote_post` and setting the HTTP protocol to 1.0 has no affect.

You can try something like this:

```
$url = 'https://example.com/users/register/';
$response = wp_remote_post( $url, array(
    'timeout' => 60,
    'redirection' => 5,
    'blocking' => true,
    'headers' => array( 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' ),
    'body' => 
        json_encode( 
            array( 
                'email'     => $email,
                'name'      => $name,
                'last_name' => $last_name,
                'password'  => $password
            ) 
        ),
    'cookies' => array()                            
    )
);
```